# How to reduce space between axis ticks and axis labels in R

Tags: r, curve

I have the below plot generated in R:

Code:

```
ecdf.bdel<-ecdf(bDE[,6])  #### cumulative distribution of a vector of numeric values

curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlim=r,xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged") ###plotting inverse ecdf curve
```

[image]

the plot is as expected. However, it leaves huge white space between axis ticks and axis labels and also between axis labels and axis labs.

Could someone offer any tip to reduce the white space.

Comment: does using `plot(inv,type="l",col="red",xlim=r,xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")`  solve the problem? You can define `inv<-1-ecdf.bdel(x)` the points you want to plot.

Comment: using plot gives the error:  `Error in .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f) : 
  object 'x' not found`

Comment: Is it possible if I could replicate your plot in my machine?I can then try.

Comment: here is the sample file ~70kb in size (http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g30af57873c71463e9998641601e872a181d43d80f)  . Basically, i am trying to plot inverse cumulative frequency plot of the values in column 1 in the file.

Comment: sorry for confusing. I mean complementary cumulative distribution funciton plot

Comment: I checked again it works fine on my machine by removing `xlim=r` and reading the file in my way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120880/discussion-between-vic-and-chas).

Comment: `ecdf.bdel<-ecdf(bDE[,6])`  #### cumulative distribution of a vector of numeric values
Is the 6th column the frequency of the V1 values?

Comment: ok You can download the plot and use it!I hope all is solved now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Insert `mgp` parameter like this, and see if it works. Also see `mar` parameter for margin from all the sides. You can use both together inside `par()` function to solve your problem.

```
   par(mgp=c(3,1,0),mar(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
   curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")
```

The `first` value in `mgp` is where your `axis labels` moves either close to or far from axis, less value means closer to axis and high value means far from axis on both the axis i.e. x and y axis.

The `second` value in `mgp` is where your `tick labels` moves either close to or far from ticks, less value means closer to tick and high value means far from ticks on both the axis i.e. x and y axis.

The `third` value in `mgp` is where your `ticks` moves either close to or far from axis line itself, less value means closer to axis line and high value means far from axis line on both the axis, i.e. x and y.

`mar` is a numerical vector of the form `c(bottom, left, top, right)` which gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot. The default is `c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1`.

Remove `xlim` from `curve()` function. Your graph condition

```
  par(mgp=c(10,4,0),mar=c(11,11,5,5)+0.1)
  curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")
```

[image]

```
 par(mgp=c(3,1,0),mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
 curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")
```

[image]

Example: Using `plot` instead of curve. It is similar

First Case:

```
    par(mgp=c(7,3,0),mar=c(8,8,5,5)+0.1)
    plot(1:10,xlab="X Axis", ylab="Y Axis", main="My Plot")
```

[image]

Second Case

```
    par(mgp=c(3,1,0),mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
    plot(1:10,xlab="X Axis", ylab="Y Axis", main="My Plot")
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason i end up having the similar plot, no matter what the mpg and mar values are!!!

Comment: Could you please share your entire code for this plot? We have the data and please add `sessionInfo()` so that we know which machine you are using.

Comment: The below three steps should work.
`>ecdf.bdel<-ecdf(df[,1]) `
`>par(mgp=c(3,1,0),mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)`
`>curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")`

Comment: it worked. but how can save it as png with 300dpi resolution?

Comment: `>png("Plot.png", width = 4, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 300)`
`>ecdf.bdel<-ecdf(df[,1])`
`>par(mgp=c(3,1,0),mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)`
`>curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged")`
`>dev.off()`

Comment: add the first and last command i.e. `png()` and `dev.off()` and in between would be your code like shown in above comment. Then check your current working directory, that will have your png file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Is this what you want? I had no other option to show the plot I will add the code if this is what you want.

This is what I did:

```
data<-read.table("Ld.txt",F)
ecdf.bdel<-ecdf(data$V1)  #### cumulative distribution of a vector of numeric values

curve(1-ecdf.bdel(x),col="red",xlab="r2",ylab="Fraction of SVs tagged") ###plotting inverse ecdf curve
```

[image]

Comment: i don't see any difference in the code with mine. however i am having this wierd space issue between the axis and labels.

Comment: I removed the xlim. Just try on the file, it should work. Also maybe possible problem with how you were reading the file. I used V1, by saying F in `read.table`

Comment: No problem! Happy I was of some use.

Comment: i was too early to post that it worked. Either solutions give me the plot with the space issue.  The problem still holds

Comment: Did you remove the `xlim` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120881/discussion-between-vic-and-chas).